# Case insensitive String in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

I have a Collection of Strings where I do not care about case sensitivity.
Currently, whenever I put a new item into the List, I put `item.toLowerCase()` and whenever I compare values, I use `contains(item.toLowerCase())`.

Is there a way to achieve this without any risk of forgetting the lower case somewhere? I cannot extend the String class since it is final, otherwise I would try something like `Collection<LowerCaseString>`.

Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: I was going to suggest wrapping a MutableList in a class that overrides its contains method, but this would be vulnerable to the Iterable.contains() function that would get called in contexts where the list is being treated as an iterable.

Comment: Doesn't `Iterable.contains()` [delegate to the Collection](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/30788566012c571aa1d3590912468d1ebe59983d/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L73) when the Iterable is a Collection?

Comment: Good point. It's probably safe, though not guaranteed by the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create your own custom collection type, and instead of subclassing `String`, which, as you said, you can't do, you can create a wrapper value class where you enforce the wrapped string to be lowercase. E.g.:

```
@JvmInline
value class LowercaseString private constructor(val wrapped: String) {
    companion object {
        fun from(string: String) = LowercaseString(string.lowercase())
    }
}
```

Of course this has the inconvenience that it requires some manual wrapping and unwrapping from/to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, your current approach is error prone and I'd bet you stepped on that already a few times :) To solve that you can create custom container that will deal this this for you automatically, so you will no longer need to normalize your data prior inserting (or anything else). Then you should update your code to use this class instead of the `List` you use currently:

```kotlin
class CaseInsensitiveList(
    private val innerList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
) : MutableList<String> by innerList {

    override fun add(element: String) = innerList.add(element.toLowerCase())
    override fun add(index: Int, element: String) {
        innerList.add(index, element.toLowerCase())
    }
    override fun addAll(index: Int, elements: Collection<String>) =
        innerList.addAll(index, elements.map { it.toLowerCase() })

    override fun set(index: Int, element: String) =
        innerList.set(index, element.toLowerCase())

    override fun contains(element: String) =
        innerList.contains(element.toLowerCase())

    override fun indexOf(element: String) =
        innerList.indexOf(element.toLowerCase())

    override fun lastIndexOf(element: String) =
        innerList.lastIndexOf(element.toLowerCase())

    override fun containsAll(elements: Collection<String>) =
        elements.all { this.contains(it) }
}
```

We only need to override the methods that require case-insensitive handling or modification.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah, especially *if* new functions get added to the Kotlin default list. I wonder, is there a good reason why there is no case insensitive string type in Kotlin?

Comment: Probably too locale-specific to be practical for the standard library.